# I am not able to find the error in my project which is arising since I used implementation 'com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Tags: android

My build Gradle code

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cheerupladies"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2'
    implementation 'android.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:21.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1")
    implementation 'com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Error Message -
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove `implementation 'android.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'`, you already have from jetpack

Also you can run `gradlew -q app:dependencies` It will remove what is wrong.